# What is the Latin word for ID/identifier?

Tags: word-request

What is the Latin word for ID, in the sense of a code or name that is unique to a thing so that it can be identified? Such codes are commonly used in databases for example.

I doubt that a word with a common etymology would fit since Gaffiot says that "identitas" is ecclesiastical.
Moreover Smith & Hall only give periphrases to translate "to identify".

And unfortunately the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identifier) has no Latin version.

Comment: Are you looking for a specific era? It sounds like you'd dislike an ecclesiastical word. There might not be good fits in the classical vocabulary.

Comment: I would prefer a term used in classical Latin, but if there is no good fit, a later word would do, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking for a suitable term in the rich vocabulary of scholastic philosophy. What about ["nomen proprium"](http://www.corpusthomisticum.org/tln.html#nomen) or ["signum distinctivum"](http://www.corpusthomisticum.org/tls.html#signum)?